# Drop down menu breaks after ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a drop down menu nav bar, that uses jquery for the drop down like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);          
        }
    );
});
```

On the same page, when I make an ajax request, the menu stops "dropping down", is there a better way to implement this drop down? I'm new to jquery and so I'm at a lost now. I've tried using .delegate, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: Does the AJAX request complete successfully or with errors? What is it doing on complete? Where is the AJAX code? C'mon man, help me you help you! :P

Comment: yes, the ajax request completes successfully. it's just a $("#refresh).load("page.php #refresh);

Comment: Open the developer tools and check the javascript console for errors after the AJAX call runs.

Comment: Is that nav is changed during the AJAX process?

Comment: You need to switch your hover event to use the `$.on()` event type. You can target the `#nav` to attach your event and tell it to only fire when over an `li`. Else, when you replace the `<li>`s in `#nav` they lose their event references.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment - I was gonna guess that you were replacing the content area containing the `ul` in the AJAX complete. In that case, the event binding could be unset, and `delegate` *should* work. I use the same thing often in sites that use `PJAX`

Try:

```
$(document).delegate('#nav ul', 'hover', function () {
    $(this).stop().slideToggle(100);
});
```

Comment: is it working to begin with? (before the ajax). add some console logs to see. does the content you're replacing in the ajax call also happen to include the <script> where all this lives? i'm confident delegate will work, and would love to help more but i'm going to guess at this point the error is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#nav li').on({
        mousenter: function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);          
        }
    );
});
```